# Need help in Laravel manimum and maximum user input in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am stuck in a problem that i want to get filter data in laravel or mysql
which later i will convert into laravel and that is i want to filter values from range slider
of warrenty
which is actually between 80 and 150 (selected by user)
and in database (mysql) i have just minimum value is 80
and  maximum value is 200

but by using the following code it only returns maximum value of the given minimum value

```
    $product = product::join('tire_brands', 'product.brand', '=', 'tire_brands.id')
    ->join('speedrating','product.speedrating','=','speedrating.id')
    ->where($whereData)
    ->when(!empty($category), function ($query) use ($category) {
        return $query->whereIn('itemtype', $category);
    })
    ->when(!empty($speedrating), function ($query) use ($speedrating) {
        return $query->whereIn('speedrating', $speedrating);
    })
    ->when(!empty($tirebrands), function ($query) use ($tirebrands) {
        return $query->whereIn('brand', $tirebrands);
    })
    ->when(!empty($minwarrenty) && !empty($maxwarrenty), function ($query) use ($minwarrenty,$maxwarrenty) {
        return $query->whereBetween('warrenty', [$minwarrenty, $maxwarrenty]);
    })
    ->when(!empty($minimum_load) && !empty($maximum_load), function ($query) use ($minimum_load,$maximum_load) {
         return $query->whereBetween('maxload', [$minimum_load, $maximum_load]);
    })
    ->when(!empty($curroff), function ($query) use ($curroff) {
        return $query->whereIn('curr_offerid', $curroff);;
    })
    ->when(!empty($sidewal), function ($query) use ($sidewal) {
        return $query->whereIn('sidewall_id', $sidewal);;
    })
    ->when(!empty($tyrtyp), function ($query) use ($tyrtyp) {
        return $query->whereIn('tyretype_id', $tyrtyp);;
    })
    ->get(['product.id','product.name as pronam',
     'tire_brands.name as brand', 'sku','slug','warrenty','speedrating','itemtype',
    'product.image','product.video','speedrating.name as speedrating','touring']);

    return $product;
```

what am i doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is.

Comment: see the result of the query before your get() raplace with toSql() method and make a dd($product); finally paste the result query in your DB client and see the results

Comment: sir , actually it is like price range(Product filter ) in laravel, but in my case i have two end range-slider the initial node is dynamically set to the  minimum warrenty value in database and the last node of range -slider is set to the maximum warrenty of the product which will be using by user to filter out warrenty range

Comment: but problem i am facing is the warrenty value the user is selecting like if it stands for 80 as minimum and user moves sildes at 89 points and maximum value of warrenty is 200 by using this code ->when(!empty($minwarrenty) && !empty($maxwarrenty), function ($query) use ($minwarrenty,$maxwarrenty) {
        return $query->whereBetween('warrenty', [$minwarrenty, $maxwarrenty]);
    }) it returns only maximum even it stands for 86 as it is also in range